# Using linq to sort list of objects with string property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `List<Perfume>` with a *string* property `OrderNumber` in format `PE_00344` with each `OrderNumber` starting with `PE_` followed by its actual order number (converted to string using `(ToString("D6"))` which is a number that increments.

Now I want to sort this `List<Perfume>` by `OrderNumber`. I am using the following

```
IEnumerable<Perfume> tempPerfumes = 
   listOfPerfumes.OrderByDescending(a => Convert.ToDecimal(a.OrderNumber.Split('_')[1]));
```

but its not working, any ideas why is it not sorting the list? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is not working? Is the result not sorted at all?

Comment: Yes; the result is same list (un-sorted)

Comment: I really should be sorted. Are you sure you are checking the order of tempPerfumes and not listOfPerfumes?

Comment: I was using the debugger and looking into a wrong list as pointed out by @kaffekopp. My bad, thanks for the help.

Comment: "looking into a wrong list " ok then we can close this question now

Comment: Why converting to decimal actually? do you expect the number to be very large or looking like this: `"PE_00344.2343"`?

Comment: When I said looking into wrong list, I meant I was looking into `source` of the `IEnumberable` while I should be looking into the `results view`. Closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an extra read-only property to your class to simplify my life:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Perfume> perfumes = new List<Perfume>();
        perfumes.Add(new Perfume("P_1002"));
        perfumes.Add(new Perfume("P_100"));
        perfumes.Add(new Perfume("P_1"));

        var sortedPewrfumes = perfumes.OrderByDescending(p => p.IntegerOrderNumber);

        foreach (var perfume in perfumes)
            Console.WriteLine(perfume.OrderNumber);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Perfume
{
    public Perfume(string orderNumber)
    {
        OrderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
    public string OrderNumber { get; }

    public int IntegerOrderNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(OrderNumber.Split('_')[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It work, you use OrderByDescending which sorts from largest to smallest.

```
List<Perfume> listOfPerfumes = new List<Perfume>();
listOfPerfumes.Add(new Perfume() { OrderNumber = "PE_00346 " });
listOfPerfumes.Add(new Perfume() { OrderNumber = "PE_00344 " });
listOfPerfumes.Add(new Perfume() { OrderNumber = "PE_00345 " });
var collection = listOfPerfumes.OrderByDescending(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.OrderNumber.Split('_')[1])).ToList();
```